# Knight's metric: ellipse and parabola.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, metric-spaces, recreational-mathematics, analytic-geometry

Knight's metric is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as the minimum number of moves a chess knight would take to travel from $x$ to $y\in\mathbb{Z}^2$. What does a parabola (or an ellipse) became with this new metric?
I apologize if the question is too vague.

Comment: You'd first have to explain what precisely you mean by "parabola" or "ellipse".

Comment: An ellipse is a curve that is the locus of all points in the plane such that the sum of whose distances from two fixed points F_1 and F_2 (the foci)  is a given positive constant.

Comment: I mean knight's distance.

Comment: The parabola is the locus of points in that plane that are equidistant from both the directrix and the focus.

Comment: Even the circle is nontrivial! It is "blurred" because some nearby points are the same distance away than the far away ones. You could definitely do some computer simulations. However, I believe for two foci, a very important parameter becomes the even-odd effect between the foci themselves. Some relative positions will yield different results.

Comment: Parabola may be problematic. What is a straight line in this case? First of all, it depends on the angle, and secondly, the traditional "line" is no longer the path of shortest distance.

Comment: The straight line is the same of standard geometry, the only properties that change are those which depend from the distance.

Comment: You could have meant to use the parabolas from standard geometry too, rather than choosing the specific definition you gave. And besides, lines are sometimes defined by sets such that two of $d(a,b)$, $d(b,c)$ and $d(a,c)$ sum to the third for any three $a,b,c$ in the line. But the real question of just what you mean by line is the fact your space is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ok, you're right. But I thought it was clear what I was saying.

Comment: It is more complicated.

Comment: Maybe we can see the problem from an other point of view. We know what is a parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with taxicab metric. Then I would like to know what is a parabola with the modified taxicab metric, that is taxicab metric subject to $|\frac{x}{y}|=2$ or $|\frac{x}{y}|=\frac12$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Noam D. Elkies's characterization of the knight's distance](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76670/what-is-the-limit-of-the-knight-distance-on-finer-and-finer-chessboards#comment195880_76670), here's an animation of $d(x,y)+d(x-a,y)$ as $a$ goes from $0$ to $30$. All cells of the same colour are on the same "ellipse" (except the darkest red ones, which have distance $\ge20$).

[image]

Comment: I have been amazed at your animation. Can you say how you have realized your animation, and, as important haow you have included it ? Is it animated gif format ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I computed a sequence of plots in Mathematica and exported the sequence as a single animated GIF.

Answer (score 2):

huge comment/hint:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&0\\ \hline
5&4&5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5&4&5\\ \hline
4&5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5&4\\ \hline
5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5\\ \hline
4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4\\ \hline
5&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&5\\ \hline
4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4\\ \hline
5&4&\color{orange}3&2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&0&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&5\\ \hline
4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4\\ \hline
5&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{red}1&4&\color{orange}3&2&\color{orange}3&4&5\\ \hline
4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4\\ \hline
5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5\\ \hline
4&5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5&4\\ \hline
5&4&5&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&\color{orange}3&4&5&4&5\\ \hline
0&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&4&5&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$

is the closest I could get it to work in PARI/GP right now for labeling it's too large an example for a true comment sadly. mods can size it down if they want/need.

Comment: This just shows the "Knight's distance" of each square from the center square, right? So it doesn't actually say anything about ellipses and parabolas, right? And why are there zeros in the corners?

Comment: Because, I didn't let PARI/GP run long enough, it was late at night. My point, was about the circles comment. because this shows that there are different groupings of the threes 3. Also it would take coloring etc to show an ellipse as defined ( As well as, a second stationary point).

Comment: knight(n)=my(a=matrix(n,n),b=[[n\2,n\2]]);for(y=1,10,b=apply(r->[[r[1]+2,r[2]+1],[r[1]+2,r[2]-1],[r[1]-2,r[2]+1],[r[1]-2,r[2]-1],[r[1]-1,r[2]-2],[r[1]-1,r[2]+2],[r[1]+1,r[2]+2],[r[1]+1,r[2]-2]],b);b=select(r->r!=[n\2,n\2]&&r[1]>-2&&r[1]<n+2&&r[2]>-2&&r[2]<n+2,fold((x,y)->concat(x,y),b));for(x=1,#b,if(b[x][1]<n+1&&b[x][1]>0&&b[x][2]<n+1&&b[x][2]>0&&a[b[x][1],b[x][2]]==0,a[b[x][1],b[x][2]]=y));for(z=1,#a,print(a[z,]));print())  is the code if anyone wants to use it.

Comment: realized it was so slow because I wasn't deleting duplicates. vecsort(,,8) around the fold was all it took to speed it up, that and now I should use an until loop not a for loop.